# Algorithm - grouping locations on map

Tags: algorithm, cluster-analysis, geospatial

I have a list of n locations, each consists of a latitude, longitude and a time stamp. These locations will be pinned on the map.

However, it is required to group locations that are close together, with the most recently changed location as centre, so that the map will not be flooded by pins.

My initial thoughts would be:

1. Sort the locations by time stamp
2. Select the latest location
3. Calculate the distance to the latest location for the n-1 locations
4. Select those locations within the radius, say, 5km, then remove them from the list
5. Repeat steps 2-4

This method works but it is highly inefficient. Worst case would be ~O(n^2).

Are there any algorithms to perform better?

Comment: https://blog.mapbox.com/clustering-millions-of-points-on-a-map-with-supercluster-272046ec5c97

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To beat the quadratic runtime, use an index.

On latitude and longitude, you may want to use an R tree, ball tree, cover tree or similar, because a kd tree apparently only works with Euclidean distance, not haversine.

Comment: R-Tree is the correct keyword. I used the implementation here https://github.com/davidmoten/rtree and the performance is superb. Thanks

Comment: But last I checked, it couldn't do Haversine distance very well. The ELKI version can. I think it uses this approach: Schubert E., Zimek A., Kriegel HP. Geodetic Distance Queries on R-Trees for Indexing Geographic Data. SSTD 2013.

Answer (score 0):

I have a hacky solution for you which might work if you are okay with approximate answer.

Generally the latitude longitudes goes several beyond several decimal points like (12.9877949,77.6095064). Now you can select only few digits after the decimal points and that generally falls within few kilometers.

Like 12.9877979,77.6095054 are closer to 12.9877949,77.6095064 so if I take only till 2 decimal points both will become 12.98,77.60 now I go through the list and pick the ones with same value.

This however won't work if you need very precise calculation